# Javascript RegEx contains

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Javascript RegEx to compare if a string matches a standart format.

I have this variable called inputName, which has the following format (sample):

> input[name='data[product][tool_team]']

And what I want to achieve with Javascript's regex is to determine if the string has the following but contains **_team** in between those brackets.

I tried the following:

```
var inputName = "input[name='data[product][tool_team]']";
var teamPattern = /\input[name='data[product][[_team]]']/g;
var matches = inputName.match(teamPattern);
console.log(matches);
```

I just get null with the result I gave as an example.
To be honest, RegEx isn't really my area, so I suppose it's wrong.

Comment: You need to escape `[` and `]`

Comment: Where is the string derived from?

Comment: @guest271314 I've edited the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You need to escape `[` and `]` as they have special meaning in regex
2. You need `.*` (or perhaps `[^[]*`) in front of `_team` if you want to allow anything there (`[^[]*` means "anything but a `[` repeated zero or more times)

Example if you just want to know if it matches:

```js
var string = "input[name='data[product][tool_team]']";

var teamPattern = /input\[name='data\[product\]\[[^[]*_team\]'\]/;
console.log(teamPattern.test(string));
```

Example if you need to capture the `xyz_team` bit:

```js
var string = "input[name='data[product][tool_team]']";

var teamPattern = /input\[name='data\[product\]\[([^[]*_team)\]'\]/;
var match = string.match(teamPattern);
console.log(match ? match[1] : "no match");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check for `DOM` elements you can use attribute contains or attribute equals selector

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name*='[_team]']")
```